# Associations in ASP.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using LINQ as the ORM in a web application project using VS2010. I defined the ER in the SQL database and simply dragged and dropped the database tables into the ORM.  The  Transfer table has 4 relationships to the Hospital table with 4 different columns.  One of the column is FK, int, not null. The other three are FK, int, null.  In the DBML the Transfer class has 4 associations to Hospital class.  The association with the required Transfer.Hospital (FK, int, not null) has the following properties.

```
Cardinality: OneToMany
Child Property: True
  Access: Public
  Inheritance Modifier: (None)
  Name = Transfers1
Parent Property
  Access: Public
  Inheritance Modifier: (None)
  Name: HospitalSrcOrDest
Participating Properties: Hospital.HospitalID -> Transfer.Hospital
Unique: False
```

The View Model used by the view page has a Transfer property of Transfer type.  The Model.Transfer.Hospital always has an integer value. However, the Model.Transfer.HospitalSrcOrDest in following page script is always null.  Shouldn't HospitalName be automatically retrieved via Hospital_Transfer1 association? Thanks.

```
<%: Model.Transfer.HospitalSrcOrDest != null ?   Model.Transfer.HospitalSrcOrDest.HospitalName : string.Empty%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my repository constructor, but it doesn't make any difference.

```
public AppRepository() //constructor
{
        // Create DataLoadOptions
        DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

        // Always fetch source or destiation hospital when we get transfer
        dlo.LoadWith<Transfer>(t => t.HospitalSrcOrDest);

        // Set these options on the DataContext
        db.LoadOptions = dlo;
....

}
```

As I understand it, LINQ uses Eager Loading as default (http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/06/linq-to-sql-deferred-loading-lazy-load.aspx).  In my View Model the Transfer is passed in by the Controller.  Should I add a HospitalSrcOrDest property to the View Model and load the value by navigating the association.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
....

Transfer transfer = base.ApplicationRepository.GetTransfer(intID);

if (transfer == null)
  {
     ViewData["Message"] = "There is no transfer record";
     return View("NotFound");
  }

TransferViewModel vm = new TransferViewModel(base.ApplicationRepository, transfer, "Edit");

return View(vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lazy load issue, are you displosing the datacontext before the hospital is accessed by the view?  By default L2S lazy loads relationships.  Meaning it doesn't get it from the database until the property is actually accessed.  If your connection is gone by the time the view accesses the hospital, it may not be able to retrieve it.  Just a guess.

To test it out, in your controller, after you perform your load/select, immediately attempt to access the hospital to force it to load.

If you want to always eager fetch the hospital, here's a link that shows you what to do:
http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/eager-fetching-of-relationships-with.html

Comment: I set the loadoption in the repository constructor as suggested, but it doesn't make any difference.  // Create DataLoadOptions
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

// Always fetch tags when we get posts
dlo.LoadWith<Post>(p => p.Tags);

// Set these options on the DataContext
db.LoadOptions = dlo;